# Convert List of Maps to Map of Lists based on Map Key

Tags: scala

Lets say I have the following list:

```
val myList = List(Map(1 -> 1), Map(2 -> 2), Map(2 -> 7))
```

I want to convert this list to a single `Map` of `Int -> List(Int)` such that if we have duplicate keys then both values should be included in the resulting value list:

```
Map(2 -> List(7, 2), 1 -> List(1))
```

---

I came up with this working solution but it seems excessive and clunky:

```
myList.foldLeft(scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,List[Int]]()) {(result,element) =>
      for((k,v) <- element) {
        if (result.keySet.contains(k)) {
          result(k) = result(k).:: (v)
        } else {
          result += (k -> List(v))
        }
      }
      result
    }
```

Is there a better or more efficient approach here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 myList
   .flatten
   .groupBy(_._1)
   .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simpler (but probably less efficient) code:

```
val myList = List(Map(1 -> 1), Map(2 -> 2), Map(2 -> 7))
val grouped = myList.flatMap(_.toList).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(l => l.map(_._2))
println(grouped)
```

> Map(2 -> List(2, 7), 1 -> List(1))

The idea is to first get `List` of all tuples from all inner `Map`s and then group them.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, we can now use [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) which is a one-pass equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` (as its name suggests):

```
// val maps = List(Map(1 -> 1), Map(2 -> 2), Map(2 -> 7))
maps.flatten.groupMap(_._1)(_._2) // Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2, 7))
```

This:

- `flatten`s the list of maps into a list of tuples (`List((1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 7))`)
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (`_._2`) (map part of group**Map**)